# How to present signed int in C?

Tags: c, int, signed

I'm new to C, and this is a newbie question:

I came across this piece of code about signed int representation:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 0x8fffffff;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

and the it returns `-1879048193`.

My current understand about signed int is that the very left side bit is used for negative or positive indication:

so `0x9` should evaluated to signed decimal `-1`, because its left side bit is `1`:

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 0x9;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me the decimal 9, not what I expected, any idea?

Comment: The most significant bit in anything is 1 by that logic. 9 is 0b1001, but consider that an int isn't 4 bits. Picture it like 0b00000000000000000000000000001001 for what would be a 32-bit int.

Comment: @MitchWheat, True, that expanded beyond my original intent.

Comment: You're not considering the number of bytes that int has on the platform on which you are compiling. See what sizeof(a) gives you.

Comment: By your logic 1 should represent -1 because it contains at least one bit that is set.  Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: @MihaiTodor @chris I got it, whatever the value the number is, the int  in my machine takes 4 bytes, so the MSB is not `0b1001`, but  `0b00000000000000000000000000001001`, thanks man

Comment: Wikipedia's article on two's complement is actually pretty good, for describing this sort of thing. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: @Joe thanks for your great resources about his topic

Comment: Also be careful when converting unsigned values (your `0x...`) to signed values. If the unsigned value is representable it is just taken as is, but if it is not the way this is done is implementation (=compiler) defined, may raise signals and stuff like that. In particular this could just be done by some rule concerning the value, and have nothing to do with the actual representation. Generally it is just a bad idea to use the bit pattern of a signed integer. Always use unsigned quatities if you need bit flags or things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the representation and what the "leftmost" (most significant) bit actually means. When the system represents an int (I'll use 32-bit) in memory, it takes up the number of bits the type defines, not however many it needs to hold the number. Depending on the type of variable, it could even take up a few more to put it in a good starting position for later access (padding/alignment).

Your integer could be represented like this, which has the value 9 in binary in the 4 rightmost bits:

```
 0b00000000000000000000000000001001
```

As you can see, the leftmost bit is certainly not 1. Your int might not be 32 bits, but anything more than 4 will give you the same story. Making the same assumptions, you could view the result of actually setting the most significant bit, which, in my test of printing 0x80000009, gave a result of -2147483639.

Comment: thanks for you answer, totally make sense, but `int a = 0x80000009;` should be '-9' in the signed, decimal representation mode? but it gives me `-2147483639`

Comment: @yozloy, 0x80000000 would be the minimum value. It would then count up to the point where 0xFFFFFFFF is -1.

Comment: @yozloy, Do be aware of the different ways systems can represent bytes. Specifically one's complement vs. two's complement and endianness.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of representing signed numbers in binary.  You are thinking of [sign-and-magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method), which is what IEEE floating point format uses.  The most significant bit of a single precision `float` or double precision `double` is used to represent the sign, as you described. Integer values in modern computers are represented in two's complement.  The range of values representable in two's complement depends on how many bits are used.  The number of bits used depends on your compiler, the target you are compiling for and the variable type you choose.  An 8-bit two's complement number can represent numbers in the range -128 to +127.  In `C` you would typically use the `char` type for a signed 8-bit value and `int` for a signed 32-bit value, all processors I'm aware of today would represent these in two's complement.  To find out how many bytes of storage your system uses to store an `int` you can use the `sizeof` operator in `C`, in most systems an `int` is 4 bytes, or 32-bits.  In an N-bit two's complement number the most significant bit (bit N-1) can, in fact, be used to determine the sign of the number, but the remaining bits are not to be interpreted as the magnitude.

See [Wikipedia's article on two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

One interesting fact of two's complement is that the most negative number representable in N bits has no representable positive counterpart in N bits.  In other words, you cannot represent the absolute value of the most negative value.  The most negative value in two's complement representable in N bits has the most significant bit (bit N-1) set, and the remaining bits 0, its value is -pow(2,N-1).  For N=8 the most negative value is 0x80 and the value is -pow(2,8-1) which is -pow(2,7) or -128.  The largest positive number representable in two's complement in 8 bits is 0x7F, a '0' in the most significant bit and '1' in the remaining bits, or pow(2,7)-1 or +127.